# Rendering error ArcGIS javascript API IE8

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have an issue when displaying features on a map in ArcGIS Javascript API V. 2.8. I want to know if this behavior is seen before, and what could cause it.

In Internet Explorer 8 the map looks like this:

[image: Internet Explorer 8 issue]

In Internet Explorer 9 and Chrome and any other browser I have tested, the map looks like this:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

The red color we see is the color of the outline of the polygons.

Below is a part of the code for drawing the polygons. As the application is quite complex, as will avoid posting the whole application here. Unfortunately I am not able to provide a direct link to the page, as it is not released yet.

```
var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(
    esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
    new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT,
        new dojo.Color([100, 0, 0, 0.5]), new dojo.Color([100, 100, 100]))
)

...

dojo.forEach(features, function (feature) {
    var graphic = new esri.Graphic(feature.geometry, symbol);
    graphic.attributes = feature.attributes;
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
});
```

The flow in the program is basicly this:

1. Page is loaded
2. Map is initialized
3. Polygons are loaded with query task
4. Polygons are drawn on map
5. Event handlers are attached ...

Comment: Unfortunately facing similar problem using graphics layer : (

Answer (score 4):

I have not solved the issue, but I have found a workaround:

If I detect Internet Explorer 8, I will just hide the outline.

```
var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(
    esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
    new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT,
        new dojo.Color([100, 0, 0, (dojo.isIE === 8 ? 0 : 0.5)]), new dojo.Color([100, 100, 100]))
);
```